# Can you use the Nether Scroll of Azumar on multiple characters?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The [Nether Scroll of Azumar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/3001257-nether-scroll-of-azumar) from Candlekeep Mysteries reads:

> Unlike most scrolls, a Nether Scroll of Azumar is not a consumable
> magic item. [...] If this
> check fails, [...] you can attempt the
> check again after another 30 days of concentrated study.
>
> When you succeed on the check, you gain the following benefits:
>
> - **Your Intelligence score increases by 2, to a maximum of 22. Once *you*
>   gain this benefit, you can’t use this scroll to increase your
>   Intelligence again.**
>
> [...]

Can multiple creatures benefit from the intelligence improvement? Or is the magic lost after the first one obtains it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The scroll is *not* a consumable magic item.

The first sentence of the description is the answer:

> Unlike most scrolls, a Nether Scroll of Azumar is not a consumable magic item.

The definition of a consumable item is:

> ##### Consumables
>
> ---
>
> Some items are used up when they are activated. A potion or an elixir must be swallowed, or an oil applied to the body. The writing vanishes from a scroll when it is read. Once used, a consumable item loses its magic.

Nothing in the description indicates that the scroll loses its potency upon completing the study, and it clearly states that it is not a consumable item. So yes, multiple creatures may benefit from the scroll, because it is a *nonconsumable* magic item, that is, an item that, once used, does not lose its magic.

Answer (score 2):

### Seems pretty clear.

If the item lost its magic after being used once, that would be a consumable item, by definition. Since the item text is clear that this is *not* a consumable item, it doesn't lose its effects after giving them once.

Consider, if the item *didn't* remain a magic item with the ability to improve intelligence after use, there would be no need to specify that it only works for a given creature one time.